# re-naming resources in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to rename resources in Azure? I create a VM and azure has created a number of resources with some unfriendly names. Specifically the NIC Azure named it Interlinkclone-nic-5a216a7b39ac47d3be6f9e6415221161, which is really a pain to type in the CLI.

I tried to create another NIC but I can find how to attach it the VM.

Comment: Do you use Azure CLI create VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure does not support rename NIC. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/11327868-allow-rename-of-network-interface-resources).

But you could create NIC with specified name firstly, when you create VM then attach it to VM. You could use the following example.

```
##create NIC with specified name
az network nic create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myNic \
    --vnet-name myVnet \
    --subnet mySubnet \
    --public-ip-address myPublicIP \
    --network-security-group myNetworkSecurityGroup

##create VM
az vm create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM \
    --location eastus \
    --availability-set myAvailabilitySet \
    --nics myNic \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-cli-complete).

If you want to add a new nic to your VM, you also could check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics).

Comment: That looks like the answer I was looking for in "the" document. I'll put those instructions to the test. Thanks.